# Why does this baked Ambient Occlusion have a dark patch on one of the faces?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I'm baking Ambient Occlusion for a game asset. It worked on the cable part (see image and blend file). But now on the camera, on its side it makes a weird split on one face, half of the face is shaded, the other not, also other faces of the camera are not shaded. But the front of the camera is shaded. What am I doing wrong here, how to get proper AO for this camera object and fix the erroneous face?

[image][image]

Comment: It looks like there are two overlapping surfaces here... don't you think ?

Comment: Nope, there is only one face.

Comment: The issue is non-planar geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]I put more geometry on the camera and then it was ok. Just divide the mesh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in vertical and horizontal direction) and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out, it has to do with the mirror modifier. Had to turn it off temporarily (for view and render), and then everything bakes good. Then turn it back on.